# what is a socket in "MySQL Enterprise Edition Subscription (1-4 socket server)"

Tags: mysql

I am looking to purchase the "MySQL Enterprise Edition Subscription (1-4 socket server)"

What does 1-4 socket server means?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They're talking about [physical processor sockets](http://www.mysql.com/products/).

> Pricing is "per Server", for 2 classes: Servers with 1-4 Sockets, and
>   Servers with 5+ Sockets

Comment: @icktoofay what's unlikely about that? That's how Oracle does pricing. http://www.mysql.com/products/

Comment: I see. You're right. I was guessing that they were talking about sockets in the network sense, but I guess they aren't.

Comment: @icktoofay Nah, it's a hosting question and belongs on a site like SuperUser. I run into licensing issues myself since I'm running multiple sockets on my workstations.

Comment: Specifically, see note 5: "Socket: is defined as a slot that houses a chip (or a multi-chip module), which contains a collection of one or more cores..."

Comment: the question is: If I have 1 server with 2 sockets. Do I need to purchase 1 or 2 licenses?

Comment: @GabrielEspinoza You would buy a license for the first class. Servers with 1-4 Sockets.